# How to write efficient list/seq functions in F#? (mapFoldWhile)

Tags: f#

I was trying to write a generic `mapFoldWhile` function, which is just `mapFold` but requires the `state` to be an `option` and stops as soon as it encounters a `None` state.

I don't want to use `mapFold` because it will transform the entire list, but I want it to stop as soon as an invalid state (i.e. `None`) is found.

This was myfirst attempt:

```
let mapFoldWhile (f : 'State option -> 'T -> 'Result * 'State option) (state : 'State option) (list : 'T list) =
  let rec mapRec f state list results =
    match list with 
    | [] -> (List.rev results, state)
    | item :: tail -> 
      let (result, newState) = f state item
      match newState with 
      | Some x -> mapRec f newState tail (result :: results)
      | None -> ([], None)
  mapRec f state list []
```

The `List.rev` irked me, since the point of the exercise was to exit early and constructing a new list ought to be even slower.

So I looked up what F#'s very own `map` does, which was:

```
let map f list = Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map f list
```

The ominous `Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map` can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs) and looks like this:

```
let map f x = 
    match x with
    | [] -> []
    | [h] -> [f h]
    | (h::t) -> 
        let cons = freshConsNoTail (f h)
        mapToFreshConsTail cons f t
        cons
```

The `consNoTail` stuff is also in this file:

```
// optimized mutation-based implementation. This code is only valid in fslib, where mutation of private
// tail cons cells is permitted in carefully written library code.
let inline setFreshConsTail cons t = cons.(::).1 <- t
let inline freshConsNoTail h = h :: (# "ldnull" : 'T list #)
```

So I guess it turns out that F#'s immutable lists are actually mutable because performance? I'm a bit worried about this, having used the prepend-then-reverse list approach as I thought it was the "way to go" in F#.

I'm not very experienced with F# or functional programming in general, so maybe (probably) the whole idea of creating a new `mapFoldWhile` function is the wrong thing to do, but then what am I to do instead?

I often find myself in situations where I need to "exit early" because a collection item is "invalid" and I *know* that I don't have to look at the rest. I'm using `List.pick` or `Seq.takeWhile` in some cases, but in other instances I need to do more (`mapFold`).

Is there an efficient solution to this kind of problem (`mapFoldWhile` in particular and "exit early" in general) with functional programming concepts, or do I have to switch to an imperative solution / use a `Collections.Generics.List`?

Comment: If you are not required to use `List<T>` you could use `ResizeArray<T>` internally in your `mapFoldWhile` and return an `T[]`. Thus you are building the result using mutability but the API of the function is immutable (this is kind of what F# does internally). Or you use an efficient streaming library such as Nessos `Streams`

Comment: Define efficient. If your folder function is expensive enough to warrant an early exit, you probably don't have a reason to care about `List.rev`. Have you measured it?

Comment: @scrwtp Yeah this appeared to be a larger problem than it is yesterday (a long monday after a longer weekend..). I was thrown off guard when I realized that `List.rev` wasn't used by the other `map` like functions, fearing it might be very slow and then failing to find an alternative. I do believe that early exits are something that should be easy to accomplish, for which Tomas pointed out a good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases, using `List.rev` is a perfectly sufficient solution.

You are right that the F# core library uses mutation and other dirty hacks to squeeze some more performance out of the F# list operations, but I think the micro-optimizations done there are not particularly good example. F# list functions are used almost *everywhere* so it might be a good trade-off, but I would not follow it in most situations.

Running your function with the following:

```
let l = [ 1 .. 1000000 ]

#time 
mapFoldWhile (fun s v -> 0, s) (Some 1) l
```

I get ~240ms on the second line when I run the function without changes. When I just drop `List.rev` (so that it returns the data in the other order), I get around ~190ms. If you are really calling the function frequently enough that this  matters, then you'd have to use mutation (actually, your own mutable list type), but I think that is rarely worth it.

For general "exit early" problems, you can often write the code as a composition of `Seq.scan` and `Seq.takeWhile`. For example, say you want to sum numbers from a sequence until you reach 1000. You can write:

```
input
|> Seq.scan (fun sum v -> v + sum) 0
|> Seq.takeWhile (fun sum -> sum < 1000)
```

Using `Seq.scan` generates a sequence of sums that is over the whole input, but since this is lazily generated, using `Seq.takeWhile` stops the computation as soon as the exit condition happens.

Comment: I completely forgot about the laziness of `Seq` functions, thank you for the reminder! If I may ask a quick follow-up question: what is more appropriate in this case in general – writing a custom version of the `map` function or using the `Seq` functions (from a functional programming perspective)? I mostly need the early exit because I don't want my state function to be called again once the invalid state is reached. (and worried about the perf of the `mapFoldWhile` because I wanted it to be as broadly applicable as `map` and thus it shouldn't be dramatically worse – but overreacted a bit)